# What do these different Normalisation value mean in this code? [TensorFlow] [Image Pre-Processing]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, sklearn-pandas

I am currently in the process of learning to utilise machine learning / tensorflow etc.
I understand what Normalization means (thanks Google):
**Normalization is a process that changes the range of pixel intensity values. Applications include photographs with poor contrast due to glare, for example.**

I came across someones code - below these are Normalization techniques someone used. But I am having trouble understanding what each **Normalization Technique** below do?

Would appreciate if someone could explain.

```
normalizers = [('x - 127.5',              lambda x: x - 127.5), 
               ('x/127.5 - 1.0',          lambda x: x/127.5 - 1.0), 
               ('x/255.0 - 0.5',          lambda x: x/255.0 - 0.5),
               ('x - x.mean()',           lambda x: x - x.mean()),
               ('(x - x.mean())/x.std()', lambda x: (x - x.mean())/x.std())]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try inputting endpoints for each one of them to find the range.

- First one translates values in the range 0 --> 255 to -127.5 --> 127.5.
- Second one translates to -1 --> 1
- Third one translates to -0.5 to 0.5
- Fourth one subtracts the mean, which results in a similar distribution centered at 0
- Fifth one calculates something called the z-score in statistics